# unable to import Django.shortcuts

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, importerror

I was working on my first  django project using the documentation. 
I am getting this error while importing django modules. I'm sure that django is successfully installed in my virtual environment. The error is:

[image: THE SCREENSHOT OF THE ERROR]

```
Unable to import 'django.shortcuts'
Unable to import 'django.http'
Unable to import 'django.contrib'
Unable to import 'django.urls'
```

Comment: Propably you have to configure your IDE to use certail virtualenv for your linting and project structure.

Comment: maybe uninstall and install help you

Answer (score 31):

If you look in your status bar you will notice you selected your global install of Python 3.7.4 and not a virtual environment. If you click on that you can then choose your virtual environment that you installed Django into.

Comment: Which you will find at ./env/bin/python3 (substitute the name of your virtual environment for "env" in that path)

Answer (score 26):

[image]

You selected your global install of Python 3.7.4 and not a virtual environment. If you click on that you can then choose your virtual environment that you installed Django into.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Screenshot]

**Solution 2: (open VS Code from an activated virtual environment):**

1. Open the terminal window
2. Activate the relevant python virtual environment
3. Ensure Pylint is installed within this virtual environment pip
   install pylint
4. Close all instances of VS Code
5. Launch VS Code from within this terminal window

(this will ensure the VS Code process will inherit all of the Virtual Env environment settings)

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. after westing hours I found this solution, so to solve this problem follow these steps:

1. open VSCode
2. go to the View tab and click on Command Pallete
3. search: Python: select interpreter
4. click on Enter interpreter path then click on Find
5. go to the virtual environment folder then go to the Scripts folder
6. select python.exe
7. after that select Python 3.x.x ('env')
8. finish :)

Answer (score 1):

It's very common in visual studio code, don't bother about it much it's just warnings. I also faced those errors while working on it. Just go ahead and complete your project first and if it still causes an error then i can guide you better.

Try these simple projects of mine to check everything is working fine or to check your django installed properly or not.

Hello world project:
https://github.com/YashMarmat/Hello-world-App-django.git

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because of change in Django version, using other environment which might exist in your system.

Answer (score 0):

import os in your settings.py file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpXnH.png)
Also, see which python version VSCode is using
I had Anaconda, Python 3.8, 3.9 in my system.

VSCode was using conda (base) virtual environment.

I was getting an Import error

I selected the correct path for Python 3.8 in VSCode Terminal

```
"C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Python\Python38"
```

It ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by switching to my dev environment where I did install Django.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But all I had to do was to select the correct Python interpreter by going into the VS Code command palette and selecting Python:Select Interpreter, and then selecting the correct interpreter. That means selecting the version of Python which you are working with and set the path for. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

this problem cause from pylanc extention. just uninstall it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).